git sparseCheckout with jgit
I have been trying to clone necessary folders and subFolders from git using jgit for spring boot rest api but according to my findings there is no direct or indirect way to do so with jgit. Is there any way I can only clone necessary folders/subFolders from my repository? If so, please comment. I am using 6.10 latest jgit version.
I tried multiple methods available on Stack Overflow and other web sites but it is cloning entire repository and all the folders/subfolders. Is there any specific library I need to import for sparseCheckout?

Seems like libgit2 is missing it, at least: https://github.com/libgit2/libgit2/issues/2263
